# A transitive verb to imply "to cause someone/something to romp"

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, word-request

Suppose I want to tell a musician that my ultimate wish is playing with them on the stage. However, I want to metaphorically describe the music-play as romping the child inside.

Something like to unleash the child inside by playing music which gives a sense of playing and joyful movements like romping around.

> My ultimate wish is to ...... the kid inside on the stage with you.

Can romp be used as a transitive verb meaning to cause someone to romp? If no, is there any verb having the same connotation?

Comment: **romp** isn't used with a direct object (**romp the child**).  The child romps.  ***Let** your inner child romp* would be idiomatic.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Thanks for the note, is there any verb that I can put in the bank to convey the same meaning?

Comment: 'to cause to romp' doesn't exist as a single transitive verb. But your sentence is not very clear. What is the agent, the do-er, of the transitive action in your sentence?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I see. I was thinking of "to unleash" or " to release" to put it in the blank but I am not sure if it means the same.

Comment: To *unleash* is figurative, and by analogy, compares the child to an animal on a leash.  Unleash your inner pit-bull. Unleash your inner tiger.  You'll have to read some Wm Blake for ideas :)

Comment: Perhaps **free your inner child** or **let loose the child inside** or **let slip the dogs of music** ;)

Comment: The prepositional phrase *on the stage with you* is problematic here. It makes sense if you have "romping" in mind, but not if you have "freeing" or "releasing" in mind.

Comment: **Allow** the child inside **to romp** on the stage with you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. I would write:

> My ultimate wish is to **bring out** the child/kid inside on the stage with you.

See [*bring out*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bring-out):

> 2. *phrasal verb*
>      Something that brings out a particular kind of behaviour or feeling in you causes you to show it, especially when it is something you do not normally show.